# Why does activator/sbt add Scala version to pure Java library dependencies?

Tags: scala, sbt, typesafe-activator

I'm using [Typesafe Activator](https://typesafe.com/activator)'s last version (1.2.8 with Scala 2.11.x).

When I add a dependency `"org.apache.httpcomponents" %% "httpclient" % "4.4-alpha1"` to my project in `build.sbt`, something like this:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.4",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % "2.3.4",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.1.6" % "test",
  "junit" % "junit" % "4.11" % "test",
  "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.10" % "test",
  "org.apache.httpcomponents" %% "httpclient" % "4.4-alpha1" // my added dependency
)
```

... and try to update the project ( in activator's cli ) I get an error:

```
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient_2.11;4.4-alpha1: not found
```

I know scala's version aren't binary compatible, but I try to get a pure-java library `org.apache.httpcomponent#httpclient`! Why does activator add "_2.11" at the end of artifactId and make wrong urls...? How to resolve it?

Comment: %% is **only** for scala libraries - (it add _2.9/_2.10/_2.11 depend on scalaVersion to artifactId). For java libraries use always single %. See @Paul Butcher comment and kindly accept.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Change the first `%%` to a single `%`. The double character version is for fetching [cross-built](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Cross-Build.html) libraries, and yours isn't.

Comment: Does that mean that the dependency info at this Apache URL is actually incorrect and should be the single `%`?   https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/dependency-info.html   (Or is there a reason for that to stay `%%` that I just don't understand?)

Comment: ... and don't forget to `reload` when you're working in the sbt shell and have just changed from `%%` to `%`...   ;)